# Why does a doOnCancel method block a sibling doOnCancel even when they are on different schedulers?

Tags: project-reactor

I was playing around with cancellations in project-reactor and came across this strange behaviour: when there are two sibling `doOnCancel` methods on the same publisher chain and they cancel on different Schedulers, the first one to run (which always seems to be the last one) blocks the one running later. Could someone explain this behaviour?

For example, when I run this code block

```
        Disposable disposable = Mono.fromCallable(() -> "A")
                .doOnCancel(() -> log.info("Cancel A"))
                .cancelOn(Schedulers.newElastic("Can-Sched-A"))
                .doOnCancel(() -> {
                    log.info("Cancel B");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                })
                .cancelOn(Schedulers.newElastic("Can-Sched-B"))
                .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

        Thread.sleep(100);
        disposable.dispose();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
```

We get the following output in which we can see the log `Cancel A` appear two seconds after `Cancel B`:

```
2020-04-15 11:16:26 [Can-Sched-B-4] INFO  somePackage.SomeTestClass - Cancel B
2020-04-15 11:16:28 [Can-Sched-A-5] INFO  somePackage.SomeTestClass - Cancel A
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. We need to understand one important thing here is all the operations are chained and each operator in the pipeline is basically a subscriber to the previous operator which acts like a publisher.

```
    Disposable disposable = Mono.fromCallable(() -> "A")
            .doOnCancel(() -> log.info("Cancel A"))              -- 5
            .cancelOn(Schedulers.newElastic("Can-Sched-A"))      -- 4
            .doOnCancel(() -> {                                  -- 3
                log.info("Cancel B");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
            .cancelOn(Schedulers.newElastic("Can-Sched-B"))       -- 2
            .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .subscribe(System.out::println);                      -- 1
```

- The last subscribe statement is what makes top publisher emit the element. The subscribe forwards the subscription to its previous upstream. It keeps going upwards and reach the top publisher and it emits the element.
- When you cancel the subscription, again it is forwarded upwards from bottom to top. So it looks like it is working backwards.
- Do note that even if you invoke dispose, the publisher could still keep on emitting elements until it is notified about the cancellation. For ex: you do some blocking operation `Thread.sleep(2000)` in the pipeline. During this time, if you were having a flux, it could have emitted multiple elements during this time as it is still not aware of the cancellation as it has to reach from bottom to top.
- Regarding the blocking behavior, Schedulers here simply is used for context switching / using some dedicated thread pools for doing the operation. Each operator in the chain will perform the operation only if the previous operation is completed.

Comment: Could you explain why the explanation you provided is not followed when the second ("B") `doOnCancel` and `cancelOn` are inside a flatMap? The response I see for that case is:

`2020-04-17 09:50:22 [Can-Sched-A-4] INFO  c.a.i.a.g.v.GetVehicleGrpcAcceptanceTest - Cancel A`
`2020-04-17 09:50:24 [Can-Sched-B-5] INFO  c.a.i.a.g.v.GetVehicleGrpcAcceptanceTest - Cancel B`

This means that the cancellation signal is now propagating from top to bottom instead of bottom to top.